# How Can I save time(day/month/year) on firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project which I use SQLite as database, I want to change it with firebase since operations are easier, but I looked at document but I don't know how to save time. Should I do it seperately like day, month, year or is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using hashmap and **ServerValue.TIMESTAMP** you can store milli seconds on the firebase.. it is the best way as per my opinion.

Comment: Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 2):

you can store value of **Firebase** using Hashmap.

```
DatabaseReference fb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
HashMap setvalues = new HashMap();
setvalues.put("last_message_time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
fb.child("rootname").updateChildren(setvalues);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to save your data as a `TIMESTAMP` like this `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`. And to get the data back, i suggest you use this method:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return "date";
    }
}
```